# What is the connection between divisors and line bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

I'm somewhat new to algebraic geometry.  I'm currently studying algebraic curves primarily over closed fields, (for future discussion let's just call such a curve C).  I was taught to think of things like $\rm{Pic}^{0}(C)$ as a set of equivalence classes of divisors on C. From what I gather, these are usually called Weil Divisors.

Some literature seems to take the approach that these classes on $\rm{Pic}^{0}(C)$ can be thought of instead as a line bundle.  For example, if I let $\epsilon$ be a two-torsion point on C, I can think of $[\epsilon]$ as an order two line bundle.

My question is what the connection is.  How can I intuitively see that this must be true?

Comment: This is the equivalence between Weil divisors and Cartier divisors. You may wish to check out Vakil's [FOAG](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) chapter 14 section 2, some of which I've summarized [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588660/weil-divisors-on-normal-noetherian-schemes/3588786#3588786). There are many other resources about this (ie [here's the search results on this website](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=weil+cartier+divisor)), and I'd encourage you to check them out and make your question more specific.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'll let you know if  have further questions.